# installing composer using curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php command

Tags: ubuntu, curl, composer-php

I have been tyrying to install Composer in my machine using the

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

command,which gives the following error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The suhosin.executor.include.whitelist setting is incorrect.
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini` or suhosin.ini (Example path [for Debian]: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini):
    suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar 

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.
```

I tried checking the files mentioned above,but none really worked.
What should I do next?

Comment: Could you locate the files indicated?

Comment: yeah i did. that was suhousin.ini or ph.ini. but they ain't editable.

Comment: You'll need to contact your (hosting?) company to ask them for a workaround. If you lack the privileges necessary to install Composer, there's not a lot that anybody else could do.

Answer (score -4):

I am done with the installation. It was a small error,arising because of a semicolon.

For greater details on composer,refer http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
For anyone who doesn't have a PHPUnit installed yet, composer is definitely the best way possible!

Comment: Downvoting because of the lack of details on the solution.